# Проблема с кнопками

Tags: c#, winforms

Controls["button" + i.ToString()].BackgroundImage = imageList1.Images[i];
Выдаёт ошибку  System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
Как можно это исправить или как менять номер кнопки? Например, есть некое значение а (предположим а=5), тогда у button5 меняем фон. Значение а может измениться, например на 4, тогда у button4 меняем фон

Answer (score 0):

1. Лучше всего заранее создать массив кнопок и обращаться по индексу.
2. Попробуйте разбить свои операции на несколько строк, и сделать [брекпоинт](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019) для дебага, чтобы посмотреть, какие имена и индексы у вас в итоге получаются.

Было

```
Controls["button" + i.ToString()].BackgroundImage = imageList1.Images[i];
```

Стало

```
var btnName = "button" + i.ToString();
var bgImage = imageList1.Images[i];
Controls[btnName].BackgroundImage = bgImage; // Здесь брекпоинт
```

3. Можно обернуть ваши действия в блок [try\catch](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) с выводов всей информации.